# Можно каким-то образом получить оставшееся время в конкретный момент времени от .animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
$p.animate({
  'background-color': 'red',
  'color': 'green',
  'padding': '10px'
}, 1000);
```

Я хочу дальше по щелчку мыши, например, остановить .animate() и узнать оставшееся время, чтобы запустить другой animate - который будет откатывать изменения первого.
Как остановить я знаю. А вот как получить оставшееся время? Или хотя бы время, которое прошло после начала анимации (я вычту его из 1000)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно с началом анимации записывать текущий `timestamp`, потом при остановке брать уже `timestamp` в момент остановки и отнимать от него записанный в момент запуска, получите время прошедшее с начала анимации

`Date.now()` возвращает количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года

```js
let time;

$('#start').on('click', () => {
  $('p').animate({
    'padding': '100px'
  }, 3000);
  time = Date.now();
});

$('#stop').on('click', () => {
  $('p').stop().animate({
    'padding': '0px'
  }, Date.now() - time);
});
```

```css
p{
  background: #ccc;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<p></p>
```